# Random passwords Project Python

Tags: python, tkinter, project

So I was trying to build a project that packs random passwords. there is only two things left. I want the password to be replaced with new one when the button is clicked again.
Then I want the password to be on the window not in the terminal.
If some one can tell me what functions I need to finish the project and I don't mind if you have any other notes about the project.

I'll put the code bellow. ⬇

```
 from tkinter import *
import random
import string

# recourses&def
string.digits
string.ascii_letters
abc = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
num = random.choice(string.digits)
pun = random.choice(string.punctuation)
abc2 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
num2 = random.choice(string.digits)
pun2 = random.choice(string.punctuation)
abc3 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
num3 = random.choice(string.digits)
pun3 = random.choice(string.punctuation)
abc4 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
num4 = random.choice(string.digits)
pun4 = random.choice(string.punctuation)

password = abc+num+pun+abc2+"  "+num2+pun2+abc3+num3+"  "+pun3+abc4+num4+pun4


def myclick():
    print(password)


# window
window = Tk()
window.title("Random Passwords")


# the label
label = Label(window, text=" Welcome To Random Passwords")
label.config(font=("Ink Free", 50, "bold"))
label.config(fg="#fc0331")
label.config(bg="#03fce7")
label.pack()



# button
theButton = Button(window, text="Click here!",
                   padx=20, pady=5, command=myclick)
theButton.pack()

# mainloop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: instead of print configure a packed label, for password gen, put the whole thing in a function and call that function (also your password generation ... it is not the best in terms of randomness and user can't even choose password length or anything and the character type sequence is always the same)

Comment: Create a  new label, inside the function? Prolly take a read about event driven programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way of generating a random string of a particular length is

```
import string
import random
def genPass(len_):#here at len argument, it should be the len of password
    printable = string.printable
    pas = ""
    for i in range(len_):
        pas+=random.choice(printable)
    return pas
```

and then make one more label and in your `myfuc` function

```
def myfunc(pas):
    label_name.config(text=pas)
```

and then create a lambda `myfu = lambda:myfunc(getPass(10))` and pass myfu variable as command for the button. And yeah instead of `getPass(10)` you can replace 10 with any number you want or even ask if from user itself

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the logic, and code layout here's a simply answer.

- First declare your window variable before myclick()
- second pack a new label in myclick() with string parameter being "text=password"

  ```
   # window
   window = Tk()
   window.title("Random Passwords")

   def myclick():
       print(password)
       passLabel = Label(window, text=password)
       passLabel.config(font=("Ink Free", 50, "bold"))
       passLabel.config(fg="#fc0331")
       passLabel.config(bg="#03fce7")
       passLabel.pack()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to say that your code for randomly generating stuff is very limited (the order will always be the same). Try putting it in a function. Make a string of your valid chars.

```
def genPassword(count):
    out = '' #output password
    charsAvailable = 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890!@#$%^&'
    for s in range(count):
        out += charsAvailable[random.randint(0, len(charsAvailable)-1) #grabs a random character from the string and adds it to the password
    return out
```

The code above does not limit itself to a pattern.

Now to display the password, you want to put a label below the button that is empty initially:

`passwordDisplay = Label(window, text="")` and pack it: `passwordDisplay.pack()`.

After this, in the myClick function, do this:

`passwordDisplay.config(text=genPassword(30))`. Whenever the button is clicked, it should generate a 30 char long password, and display it.

Answer (score 0):

Changes I've made to your code:
I replaced the `myclick` function with a `create_password` function. Then, inside `create_password`, I made a tuple called `my_tuple` containing all of the requirements of the password characters. I also made an empty list called `my_list`. After that, I iterated through `my_tuple`, generated a random character out of each requirement in the tuple and appended every character to `my_list`. I then turned `my_list` to a string called `password` and set the text of a new label I created to `password`. That label is being displayed on a small `Toplevel` widget/window called `window2`. Modified code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string

# window
window = Tk()
window.title("Random Passwords")
password = ""

def create_password():
    global password
    my_tuple = (string.ascii_letters, string.digits, string.punctuation, string.ascii_letters, string.digits,
                string.punctuation, string.ascii_letters, string.digits, string.punctuation, string.ascii_letters,
                string.digits, string.punctuation)

    my_list = []

    for i in my_tuple:
        my_list.append(random.choice(i))


    password = "".join(my_list)
    label2.config(text=password)


# window that displays the generated password
window2 = Toplevel(window)
window2.title("Password")
window2.geometry("20x20+450+300")

# the label
label = Label(window, text=" Welcome To Random Passwords", font=("Ink Free", 50, "bold"), fg="#fc0331", bg="#03fce7")
label.pack()
label2 = Label(window2, text="")
label2.pack()



# button
theButton = Button(window, text="Click here!",
                   padx=20, pady=5, command=create_password)
theButton.pack()

# mainloop
window.mainloop()
```